# Determine if $y(x)=e^{2x}-3e^{-x}$ is a solution of the differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine if $y(x)=e^{2x}-3e^{-x}$ is a solution of the differential equation $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=0$

This is my very first differential equation problem and I just wanted to see if I went about solving it correctly.

So since this is a second order differential equation I took the second and first derivatives of $y(x)$:

$\frac{dy}{dx}=2e^{2x}+3e^{-x}$

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=4e^{2x}-3e^{-x}$

So plugging this into $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=0$

I get:

$4e^{2x}-3e^{-x}-2e^{2x}+3e^{-x}-2(e^{2x}-3e^{-x})=0$

Which ultimately equals $6e^{-x}=0$

So this is not a solution to the differential equation, correct?

Comment: There is a sign error in the line after "I get".

Comment: @AndréNicolas, thanks!  That's pretty frustrating... haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made sign mistake.

So plugging this into $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}-\frac{dy}{dx}-2y=0$ you should get

$$4e^{2x}-3e^{-x}-(2e^{2x}+3e^{-x})-2(e^{2x}-3e^{-x})=0$$ distribute the negative correctly (first set of parentheses), and you should satisfy the equality.